# Automation Anywhere Enterprise For Loop in excel file

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I'm learning AAE for like a week and I have problem with for loop in excel file. I have prepared table with Vendor Id, Material, and order Quantity:

```
Vendor  Material    Quantity
25000   1545454      100
64003   7854786     1024
25000   5896471      250
25000   3336661      900
64003   7854786     2048
25000   3336691      900
```

And I wanted to validate table if there is any redundancy in material and vendor column.
I have created 6 variable 2 for each column and named them :
POv, POm, POq and Vpo, Mpo, Qpo.
And of course 2 itterators Itteraor2 and Itterator3 that I am incremanting in 2 loops.

[image]

Problem is that my loop is infinite, while I wanted only to itterate 6 times (number of rows) and additionally it is messaging me that row 2 AND 3 has the same vendor ID and material ID what is not true. 
Could somebody tell me what is wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few corrections in the code:

**First:**

For the inner loop, consider placing the variable operation between `End If` and `End Loop`.

**Second:**

For the outer loop (before`$iterator3$+1`), ensure that the inner loop counter is set like this

`$iterator2$`= `$iterator3$+1`
so that it does not compare the previous rows again.

**P.S:** Avoid using any absolute(C:\Users\xxx\yyy.xlsx) path name for opening files/spreadsheet instead use the System variable `$AAApplicationPath$` this will help you to deploy the bot from a Control room to a Bot Runner

Answer (score 0):

After adding system variable there is a file named "desktop.ini" created and the data gets added while adding data from all xls files from the folder.